# invalid package name and identity info

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

certification info is not the same of app identity when .appxbundle uploaded

ERROR:

Invalid package family name: 29341FgyghstudioLtd.h3xagon_qg7s8j2t6mv7c (expected: 29341FgyghstudioLtd.h3xagon_7w4g6jt392j6w)

Invalid package publisher name: CN = fgsoftwarestudio (expected: CN = 61D3CB2C-EA3E-46F4-8EFA-0B01B1197757)

i.e: is a unity uwp generated project

[appxmanifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfD1w.png)

[app identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHkYV.png)

[error on microsoft partner center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNULy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this creating a new certificate from uwp project generated by unity engine